# Is slop in the headtube normal?

Tags: road-bike, maintenance

I have a carbon Fibre front fork "BSC profile design" and when I tighten up all the screws on it snugly there is no movement (forward backward) but I go out for a ride and by the end there is a small amount of slop in it (like when pressing the front brake the fork slides back a few mil before hitting the back of the headtube) is this normal? Or is there something I need to do to reduce the slop?

Comment: Are you sure the slope is not between the brake pads and brake calipers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not normal - any knock is also going to accelerate wear so you must fix it soon.

Did you loosen the stem bolts before tightening down the headclamp?
See [1].  The tightening order is the same for all materials, but the torques are vastly different. The torque range is usually 4-8 Nm for the head clamp for carbon forks, similar for stem clamps. You can use a special carbon grease to increase friction to that you succeed at low torques.  See [2]

Does it have a couple of years or more of wear on it?  Head clamps wear out.  Head clamps for carbon frames are remarkably skimpy things.

[1] http://www.artscyclery.com/learningcenter/tightenyourheadset.html

[2] [Attaching a stem to a carbon steerer: how much torque?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2843/attaching-a-stem-to-a-carbon-steerer-how-much-torque)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I don't know how I got it in my head to tighten the handlebars before the end cap. The slop is gone again, I'll give it a good ride tomorrow and see if this solves the issue

Comment: "I don't know how I got it in my head to tighten the handlebars before the end cap"  ... I don't know but it might be the same way I did!  And I said the same thing.